# KVC: NSConcreteValue unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, key-value-coding, unrecognized-selector

I'm having a object MyObject setup like this

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    int time;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) int time;
@end
```

I'm trying to use KVC to set the value and my code looks like this:

```
MyObject* obj = [MyObject alloc] init];

int val = 2;
NSValue* nsvalue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&val objCType:@encode(int)];
[obj setValue:nsvalue forKey:@"time"];   // here I get the exception
```

When I run this code, I get an exception like this:

```
-[NSConcreteValue intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e0f670
```

I've tried with other data types (float) and get the same exception. I've also tried to get the value using `valueForKey` and that works well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`- setValue:forKey:`'s `value` not means `NSValue` here. You should box the scalar `int` into `NSNumber` but not `NSValue`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002171-BAJEAIEE

Comment: Thanks. I just discovered that too by trial and error, but you were faster with an answer here :)